# Edit in grid view not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, quick-edit, gridview

I am having an issue with editing in grid view. I have few document libraries where users are updating the metadata using grid view.

The problem we have is that it is working in some of the document libraries, and in some, it doesn't work.

All the document libraries have the same metadata.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this issue because you have not entered (or entered unsupported) values for all required fields in document library.

Make sure you are doing below things correctly:

1. Show all required columns in library view & enter values for all columns in grid view
2. Make sure there are no documents which are checked out by someone else while editing in grid view.

Answer (score 0):

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

1.Check if set the **Column Validation** for some columns.

For example: I set the following Column Validation in the Test field

[image]

[image]

2.Check if some columns enable "**Enforce unique values**" feature.

[image]

3.Check this document is **checked out** by others

[image]

[image]

4.You can click on the **red ! icon**, you can get an obvious error prompt.

[image]

[image]

5.Switch to **Classic SharePoint mode** for testing

6.Clear browser cache

7.Use other browsers for testing

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive information. The issue has been resolved by itself. Not sure what happened, but no one has to experience the problem.

Comment: Hi Harris. Um, anyway. I'm still happy to hear that your problem has been solved. Have a nice day!